# Why is my OrderBy running forever with this comparator?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting

I have a class,

```
public class NullsAreLast : IComparer<int?>
{
    public int Compare (int? x, int? y)
    {
        if(y == null)
            return -1;
        else if(x == null)
            return 1;
        else
            return (int)x - (int)y;
    }
}
```

which is self-explanatory on how it is supposed to work.

Whenever I run

```
arr.OrderBy(i => i, new NullsAreLast())
```

with at least two `null` values in `arr` it runs forever! Any idea why?

Comment: your sorting is not stable - what if both are null? that should return 0.

Comment: What is `arr` exactly?

Comment: @DanielA.White still, it shouldn't run "forever". As soon as it hits a null in either x or y, it should return right away. I'm guessing `arr` is some delayed query that does some funky stuff behind the scene

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vM3brF

Comment: Always provide a minimal but ***complete*** program that allows us to reproduce the problem.  Your program is minimal, but *incomplete*.

Comment: Because x is the first member in comparison, It should return -1 when `x == null` and return 1 when `y == null`.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that a sorting algorithm may compare the same two values several times over the process of ordering the whole sequence. Because of this, it's very important to be aware of all three possible results: less than, greater than, and equal.

This is (mostly) fine for your integer comparison at the end (the subtraction operation). There are some weird/rare edge cases when working with floating point numbers instead of integers, and calling `.CompareTo()` is the preferred practice anyway, but subtraction is usually good enough in this case. However, the `null` checks here are a real problem.

Think about what happens as a list is nearly finished sorting. You have two `null` values that have both made their way to the front of the list; the algorithm just needs to verify they are in the correct position. Because both `x` and `y` are `null`, your function should return `0`. They are equivalent (for this purpose, at least). Instead, the code always returns `-1`. The `y` value will always be less than then `x` value, and so the algorithm will always believe it still needs to swap them. It swaps, and tries to do the same thing again. And again. And again. And again. It can never finish.

Try this instead:

```
public class NullsAreLast : IComparer<int?>
{
    public int Compare (int? x, int? y)
    {
        if(!y.HasValue)
        {
            if (!x.HasValue) return 0;
            return -1;
        }
        if(!x.HasValue) return 1;
        return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The minus operation at the end of your Compare method isn't appropriate for comparison.  You need to handle exactly three possibilities - x is bigger, y is bigger, or they are the same.

> **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx)**
>
> Compares two objects and returns a value indicating whether one is
>   less than, equal to, or greater than the other.

With this code, suppose X was 1000 and Y was 15.  Your result would be 985, which doesn't make sense here.

Given your code and method name, I'm going to guess what you meant is this:

```
public class NullsAreLast : IComparer<int?>
{
    public int Compare (int? x, int? y)
    {
        if(y == null)
            return -1;
        else if(x == null)
            return 1;
        else{
            int diff = x - y;
            if (diff == 0) return 0;  //same
            if (diff < 0) return 1;   //y was bigger
            if (diff > 0) return -1;  //x was bigger
        }   
    }
}
```

You could even smash it into a horrible one-liner:

```
return (y==null?-1:(x==null?1:(x-y==0?0:(x-y<0?1:-1))));
```

Comment: The minus is fine for this. It handles all three conditions for integers. The problem comes earlier (see my answer).